# CSS animation move dot diagnoally

Tags: css, css-animations

Here is the animation that I want to create step by step:

1. A dot is located in the top left corner
2. The dot expands diagonally to the bottom right corner
3. The expanded dot shrinks to a dot to the bottom right corner

Here is [a snippet](http://codepen.io/cguo/pen/NNgoNy) that accomplishes step 1 & 2 but I don't know how to do step 3.

The dot is rotated by -45 degrees to make it expand diagonally:

```
.a 
  top: 0
  left: 0
  background-color: $slack-green
  transform: rotate(-45deg)
  transform-origin: top left
  animation: slack-animation-a $duration infinite
```

Then, it is animated like this:

```
@keyframes slack-animation-a 
  0%
    top: 0 
    height: $dot-diameter

  33%
    top: 0
    height: $slack-size
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
.c-slack {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  margin: 80px auto;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
}
.c-slack_dot {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}
.a {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #3eb991;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  animation: slack-animation-a 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes slack-animation-a {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    height: 18px;
  }
  33% {
    top: 0;
    height: 96px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="c-slack"><span class="c-slack_dot a"></span>
</div>
```

Any help and suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the appropriate `height` along with `top` and `left` settings within the keyframes configured for the animation.

**Keyframes Code (Sass):**

```
@keyframes slack-animation-a 
  0%
    top: 0px
    left: -$dot-diameter/2
    height: $dot-diameter

  33%
    top: 0px
    left: -$dot-diameter/2
    height: ceil($slack-size * 1.414)

  66%, 100%
    top: round($slack-size - $dot-diameter / 1.3667)
    left: round($slack-size - $dot-diameter * 1.1667)
    height: $dot-diameter
```

Frames at 66%, 100% are both required because the frame at 66% is the time when the line changes to a dot and 100% frame makes the element retains its final state (the dot) for a third of the animation duration. Without the 100% frame, the element would slide back to its original state (dot at top-left) as soon as it has become a dot again. Without the 66% frame, something very similar would happen. So, if the element needs to be *seen* at its final position then both frames are critical.

**Snippet:**

```css
body {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
.c-slack {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  margin: 80px auto;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
}
.c-slack_dot {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}
.a {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  animation: slack-animation-a 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes slack-animation-a {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
    left: -9px;
    height: 18px;
  }
  33% {
    top: 0px;
    left: -9px;
    height: 136px;
  }
  66%,
  100% {
    top: 83px;
    left: 75px;
    height: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="c-slack"><span class="c-slack_dot a"></span>
</div>
```

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/ONgdov)

Comment: The codepen link's animation looks different from the SO snippet.

Comment: Sorry I was trying out something else and forgot that autosave was on. Please check now :) @Cheng

Comment: I don't know if you noticed, at the very end of the animation the dot moves slightly to the bottom right by a few pixels. Also, 66% and 100% are identical, is this necessary?

Comment: @Cheng: That's because of the math. The element is being scaled along a diagonal and so the height should be more the sides * 1.414 (trigonometry) + the rotation and transform-origin values mean there is more calculation involved.

Comment: @Cheng: [This](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/ONgdov) is the closest that I could get it to with all the calculations updated. You'd notice a slight shiver at the end but nothing could be done about it because there is a small correction happening at the end.

Comment: really appreciate all the time and effort you have put into this! Thank you! The method I come up with is the only way that I can think of to simulate a diagonal expansion. I wonder if you have better suggestions.

Comment: You're welcome @Cheng. I'll think about it and let you know if there are any better methods. Your method seems a good enough one for this kind of effect (just that it needs a lot of math for precision).